# Android PHP - Upload photo to mySQL using UPDATE

Tags: php, android, mysql, upload, photo

I have an android app that will upload a photo to mysql database. This photo serves as a profile photo. Which means I must UPDATE the existing row of the user.

Table - user
Columns - id, name, photo, schoolid, password

Using the id of the user, he will upload the photo in his row.

I followed this tutorial.

```
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/
```

This is the script.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $schoolid = $_POST['schoolid'];
    $photo = $_POST['photo'];
    require_once('dbConnect.php');
    $sql ="SELECT schoolid FROM user WHERE schoolid = '$schoolid'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $schoolid = $row['schoolid'];
    }
    $path = "uploads/$schoolid.png";
    $actualpath = "http://192.168.0.20/quizmaker/$path";
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET photo = '$actualpath' WHERE schoolid = '$schoolid'";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($photo));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

In my android.

```
String photo = getStringImage(bitmap);
Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<>();
params.put("photo", photo);
params.put("schoolid", schoolid);
```